# C# Converting a Percentage Value read from Excel to a Double

Tags: c#

I am reading a `percentage value` from an `excel` file, and I need this value to be of type `double`.

I am using `xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "A1")Value2` to retrieve the value. Casting / converting to a double isn't working.

How can I convert this `percentage` to a `double`?

Comment: What does the input received from Excel look like? How is it formatted?

Comment: 87.5%       56.34%      Like that? very simple percentages

Comment: Thank you for the edit =) looks much nicer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input is 87.5%, you'll need to get rid of the % sign first:

```
var inputText = "87.5%";
var doubleValue = Double.Parse(inputText.Replace("%", ""));
```